# Searching for CloudBlobDirectory.ListBlobs Method Equivalent in WinUI 3 Using Azure.Management.Fluent Package

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, winui-3

Our old ASP.Net application referenced `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent` for the code below.

```
    private static void DeleteBlobs(IAzure azure, string sourceContainer, string dbName)
    {
        var sAcc = GetStorageAccount(azure);
        CloudBlobClient bClient = sAcc.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer srcCont = bClient.GetContainerReference(sourceContainer);     

        var srcDir = srcCont.GetDirectoryReference(dbName);
        var blobs = srcDir.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true).ToList();

        foreach (CloudBlockBlob blob in blobs)
        {
            CloudBlockBlob dBlob = srcCont.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name);

            //Delete the source blob after copying
            dBlob.Delete();
        }
    }
```

Our new WinUI 3 code, which uses the `Azure.Management.Fluent` package, is as follows. Similar, but the `CloudBlobDirectory.ListBlobs` does not exist, and we cannot seem to find an equivalent that will work for the `foreach` statement.

```
    public static async void DeleteBlobsTest(string dbName) 
    {
        var sAcc = GetStorageAccount(_StorageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient bClient = sAcc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer srcCont = bClient.GetContainerReference(_ActiveProjectsContainer);

        var srcDir = srcCont.GetDirectoryReference(dbName);
        var blobs = srcDir.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true).ToList(); //ListBlobs() does not exist


        foreach (CloudBlockBlob blob in blobs)
        {
            CloudBlockBlob dBlob = srcCont.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name);

            //Delete the source blob after copying
            await dBlob.DeleteAsync();
        }
    }
```

We tried replacing var `blobs = srcDir.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true).ToList();` with the two lines of code below, but it did not work, giving the error: `Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory' to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.` Both our original and replacement return `IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>` interface enumeration, but different implementations, it seems. In any case, are there any workable replacements for `ListBlob()` in the WinUI 3 package?

```
        BlobResultSegment blobSegment = await srcDir.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(new BlobContinuationToken());
        IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = blobSegment.Results;
```

Comment: "Azure.Management.Fluent" spelled like that doesn't seem to exist. You want to use this Azure.Storage.Blobs now and this has nothing to do with WinUI3 specifically

Comment: Interesting. "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent" doesn't come up for me either anymore, but it is in my installed and indicated as deprecated. I'll give the other a look and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Per Simon Mourier's comment. The best solution seems to be to use a different package and write the code accordingly. The package I had is now deprecated and doesn't seem to appear anymore in NuGit.

I added the package: `Azure.Storage.Blobs`

My code now looks like this, similar but not an exact match with the original:

```
    public static void DeleteBlobs(string dbName)
    {
        BlobServiceClient bSvcCl = GetStorageAccountTest(_StorageConnectionString);

        BlobContainerClient contCl = bSvcCl.GetBlobContainerClient(_ActiveProjectsContainer);

        var blobs = contCl.GetBlobs();

        foreach(BlobItem blob in blobs)
        {
            BlobClient sourceBlob = contCl.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
            sourceBlob.Delete();
        }
    }
```